# Symfony2 doctrine:generate:entities wrong methods name

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

My entity class is:

```
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\TipiVendita", inversedBy="idAgente")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="tipi_vendita_agenti",
 *   joinColumns={
 *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_agente", referencedColumnName="id")
 *   },
 *   inverseJoinColumns={
 *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_tipo_vendita", referencedColumnName="id")
 *   }
 * )
 */
private $idTipoVendita;

/**
 * Constructor
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->idTipoVendita = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}
```

and when i use the command 'doctrine:generate:entities', methods that generates are wrongly named:

```
/**
 * Add idTipoVendita
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\TipiVendita $idTipoVendita
 * @return Agenti
 */
public function addIdTipoVenditum(\AppBundle\Entity\TipiVendita $idTipoVendita)
{
    $this->idTipoVendita[] = $idTipoVendita;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove idTipoVendita
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\TipiVendita $idTipoVendita
 */
public function removeIdTipoVenditum(\AppBundle\Entity\TipiVendita $idTipoVendita)
{
    $this->idTipoVendita->removeElement($idTipoVendita);
}

/**
 * Get idTipoVendita
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
 */
public function getIdTipoVendita()
{
    return $this->idTipoVendita;
}
```

How can i have addIdTipoVentita instead of addIdTipoVenditum, removeIdTipoVendita instead of removeIdTipoVenditum?

**Update**

The issue is that doctrine don't generate properly my entity! It generates methods names with the doctrine inflector component and add these kind of suffixes. How can i configure it in the right way?

Comment: Place cursor right after `addIdTipoVenditum`, press backspace twice, press `a`. Do the same for `removeIdTipoVenditum`. Done. What's the problem?

Comment: Yes, i'm not stupid. Real problems come when i try to use forms which try to call addIdTipoVenditum and/or removeIdTipoVenditum

Comment: So you didn't described the issue, because it's not doctrine's command being the problem, but the form.

Comment: The entity management is maded direcly by doctrine. If the entities were properly generated there would be no problems

Comment: You can modify entity as you want, therefore it's not Doctrine's issue. Doctrine's command is just a helper tool.

Comment: Why when i change methods names my form doesn't work anymore? It try to find the addIdTipoVenditum

Comment: I don't know, but it's the form as you just said. You didn't provided suitable code, exception stacktrace etc. That's why I said that you didn't actually described the issue in you question post. :-)

Comment: The issue is that doctrine don't generate properly my entity! It generates methods names with the doctrine inflector component and add these kind of suffixes. How can i configure it in the right way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Riccardo, You should name your properties in English. 
And you should be aware that you are in a Object world, you work with objects and not with object_ids.

So the Entity `TipiVendita` should be named something like `SellType` (english, singular).

While the `idTipoVendita' field, if I understand, should enforce an N-M relation with SellType and Agents, so it should be named something like sellTypes (english, plural because it is a collection).

To make a long story short `idTipoVendita` - beeing a field for a collection, is seen as a plural form and is singularized in idTipoVenditum (just like "Curricula" and "Curriculum").

Best regards.

Comment: Thank you man. I've created entities directly from db and names are generated by doctrine and not by me

Comment: Ok,  it's up to you to modify the names of the properties of your entities, then with doctrine:generate:entity you get proper constructors, getters and setters.

Comment: Property names are strictly tied to `inversedBy` and `mappedBy` of doctrine's annotations, so you must change them accordingly